# Not able to edit or save files in atom in /var/www

Tags: permissions, lamp, 18.10, atom

I am new to Ubuntu (and Linux).

As you might know after installing LAMP for Ubuntu, the default folder for the files `/www` lies inside the `/var` folder

The `/var` folder lies in the root.

Now, of course, I will need to make changes to the web files kept inside the `/www` folder to complete my website.

Now when I add this folder to the Atom, and try to edit any file e.g. index.php, I am not able to

I can understand that this is a file permission issue of the user and group. I have searched a lot but am unable to resolve the issue.

Comment: Is `/var/www/myfoldername` for Apache files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LAMP so I presume it's an APACHE setup. Two things to do

1. Add yourself to the apache group www-data

   ```
   sudo adduser $USER www-data
   ```
2. Make apache user the owner of the `/var/www/floder_name` folder

   ```
   sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/folder_name
   ```
3. Logout and back in again for it to take effect.

Bonus: Make the default user and group www-data so you don't have to keep updating

```
sudo setfacl -d -m u:www-data:rwx,g:www-data:rwx,o::rx /var/www/folder_name
```

Note: I used a `775` permission, you can use that which suits your setup!